# How do I link Particle data between objects?

Tags: particles

Normally if I have a material and want to put that material on say, 50 different objects, then I would select one object with that material, and then select the rest of the objects, hit Ctrl + L, and the material data would be copied to all the objects.

I have the exact situation I described above, except that I want to copy an object constraint from one object to all the other objects. Unfortunately the Ctrl + L menu doesn't have a "Particle" button.

How do I copy this Part to all the other objects?

Answer (score 5):

- select all the objects you want the particle system to be linked to
- select the object with particle system as last (so it is the active object)
- from particle system list select the system to be linked (the active one or all the particle systems)

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

It basically is just linking the modifier.

**Here is the steps in Blender 2.79b:**

- Select object that you want the particle to be linked to.
- Select the object with particle.
- Hit Ctrl + L on your keyboard.
- Select Modifier.